# What is simplest way to prevent frame drop in flutter application on heavy task?

Tags: multithreading, flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I've ran into problem getting UI lags when this line is running:

```dart
var keys = crypt.generateKeys();
```

Here is the full function:

```dart
void createKeys(_) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var keys = crypt.generateKeys();  // laggy line
    prefs.setString('persPriv', keys[0]);
    prefs.setString('persPub', keys[1]);
    prefs.setString('mesPriv', keys[2]);
    prefs.setString('mesPub', keys[3]);
  }
```

I was trying to wrap this function with `Isolate`.

```dart
Isolate.spawn(createKeys, null);
```

But I've got an error:

```dart
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Isolate.spawn expects to be passed a static or top-level function
```

What is the correct way to start isolates to prevent frame drops and UI lagging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can use SharedPreferences within an Isolate without support for MethodChannel / accessing platform-specific underlying OS frameworks on iOS / Android.

You would need to use [FlutterIsolate or a similar package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate) to provide that support.

[chunhunghan has a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66236950/2301224) detailing this.

Alternatively, you could run the `crypt.generateKeys()` by itself in your `Isolate.spawn()` call and use the results after in a separate method accessing `SharedPreferences`.  (Assuming that `crypt` package is also not relying on platform-specific code.)